# Does two python codes running at the same time access same randomness?

Tags: python, numpy, random, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am running 36 jupyter notebooks on AWS instance. The code generates some experimental data based on some probability distribution. I do realize that I cannot multi-thread as it uses the same randomness. I'm not sure if it is the same case if I run the python script separately.

I would like to know if the python code in the background accessing the same randomness?

Currently I'm using numpy.random. I do realize that I can use os.random to avoid this problem. But I really don't prefer it as I have to do a lot of wrap around to get the necessary distribution I require.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as long as the `seed` is different, they should return different results.

Comment: @Jaxi I am not seeding manually. Does the OS initialize same RandomState for all the scripts?

Comment: According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState, the default seed used is None, which in turn means it seeds from /dev/urandom, so the two notebooks should see different random data.

Comment: You realize that this would be trivially easy for you to test?

Comment: You designed it wrong. For reproducibility you have to read and store RNG before you start your sampling - on each thread/process/node. Otherwise, if you hit bug, how do you know how to debug it?